# PySpark Groupby and Filter based on Regex

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, filtering

I have a PySpark df with

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
print(df.groupBy(['issue_month', 'loan_status']).count().show())

+-----------+------------------+-----+
|issue_month|       loan_status|count|
+-----------+------------------+-----+
|         06|        Fully Paid|12632|
|         03|        Fully Paid|16243|
|         07|           Default|    1|
|         02|        Fully Paid|16467|
|         06|           Default|    1|
|         07|   In Grace Period|  289|
|         01|       Charged Off| 5975|
|         05|       Charged Off| 5209|
|         02|Late (31-120 days)|  184|
|         11|           Current|17525|
|         12|   In Grace Period|  369|
|         10|        Fully Paid|19222|
|         04|        Fully Paid|16802|
|         07|       Charged Off| 7072|
|         06|       Charged Off| 4589|
|         04| Late (16-30 days)|   98|
|       null|              null|    2|
|         10|Late (31-120 days)|  621|
|         07| Late (16-30 days)|  125|
|         10|           Default|    2|
+-----------+------------------+-----+
```

I would like to filter for only loan_status is late which could be values "Late (16-30 days)" or "Late (31-120 days)". So I tried:

```
print(df.groupBy(['issue_month', 'loan_status']).count().filter((F.col('loan_status')=='Late (31-120 days)')|F.col('loan_status')=='Late (16-30 days)').show())
```

This fails but regardless, it's dirty. I would like to do like in pandas where I can simply filter for a regex. In my case it would be something along the lines of:

```
F.col('loan_status').contains("Late")
```

Comment: try: `df.groupby(..).count().filter("loan_status rlike 'Late'")`

Answer (score 1):

Pyspark also have **`contains()`**(or) **`like`** function we can use in `.filter()`

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data
df.show()
#+-----------+------------------+
#|issue_month|       loan_status|
#+-----------+------------------+
#|         10|        Fully Paid|
#|         10|           Default|
#|         10|Late (31-120 days)|
#+-----------+------------------+

#in filter query convert loan_status to lower case and look for substring late.
df.groupBy("issue_month","loan_status").\
count().\
filter(lower(col("loan_status")).contains("late")).\
show()

#by using like function
df.groupBy("issue_month","loan_status").\
count().\
filter(lower(col("loan_status")).like("late%")).\
show()

#i would suggest filtering rows before groupby will significantly increases the performance in bigdata!!
df.filter(lower(col("loan_status")).like("late%")).\
groupBy("issue_month","loan_status").\
count().\
show()

#+-----------+------------------+-----+
#|issue_month|       loan_status|count|
#+-----------+------------------+-----+
#|         10|Late (31-120 days)|    1|
#+-----------+------------------+-----+
```

---

We can use **`.agg(sum("count"))`** to get the sum of count regardless issue_month.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as _sum
df.show()
#+-----------+------------------+
#|issue_month|       loan_status|
#+-----------+------------------+
#|         10|        Fully Paid|
#|         10|           Default|
#|         11|Late (31-120 days)|
#|         11|Late (31-120 days)|
#|         10| Late (16-30 days)|
#+-----------+------------------+

df.filter(lower(col("loan_status")).contains("late")).\
groupBy("issue_month","loan_status").\
count().\
agg(_sum("count").alias("sum")).\
show()

#+---+
#|sum|
#+---+
#|  3|
#+---+
```

---

```
df.filter(lower(col("loan_status")).like("late%")).\
groupBy("issue_month","loan_status").\
count().\
groupBy("loan_status").\
agg(_sum("count").alias("sum_count")).\
show()

#same result will get by using one group too
df.filter(lower(col("loan_status")).contains("late")).\
groupBy("loan_status").\
agg(count("*").alias("sum_count")).\
show()

#+------------------+---------+
#|       loan_status|sum_count|
#+------------------+---------+
#|Late (31-120 days)|        2|
#| Late (16-30 days)|        1|
#+------------------+---------+
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
df.filter(lower(col("loan_status")).contains("late")).\
groupBy("issue_month").\
agg(count("*").alias("sum_count")).\
show()

#+-----------+---------+
#|issue_month|sum_count|
#+-----------+---------+
#|         10|        1|
#|         11|        2|
#+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: These work great but how do I get a sum by each month irregardless wether it's Late 31-120 days or Late 16-30 days? Is there a way to do this without doing another groupby?

Comment: @Odisseo, Please check my **Update** in the answer!

Comment: mhmhmh I'm getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: @Odisseo, I think you are not using spark `sum` function try to import `from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as _sum` then use **`_sum`** instead of sum.. i have updated the answer too..
`

Comment: That did work! But it's not what I'm looking for... sorry. What I'm looking for is a df just like the one you had with the first group by, except without a separate count between rows that are between 30 and 120 and rows that are between 16 and 30.

Comment: Would it be possible to have that without writing a second group by>?

Comment: I'm very sorry but this is not quite it... I am looking for this as an output:+-----------+----------+
|issue_month|sum(count)|
+-----------+----------+
|         01|       274|
|         02|       204|
|         03|       291|
|         04|       459|
|         05|       404|
|         06|       410|
|         07|       638|
|         08|       522|
|         09|       482|
|         10|       759|
|         11|       643|
|         12|       871|
+-----------+----------+

Comment: @Odisseo, Ok.. check `update` once! (Just in case if you want count for all loan_status then remove filter condition.)